# View controller detached

Tags: ios

I'm updating an iOS app and receiving the following warning when presenting a view controller: `Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <UINavigationController: 0x984e640>.`

The app delegate loads the main view controller like this:

```
[self.window setRootViewController:[MainViewController sharedInstance]];
[[MainViewController navigationController]setViewControllers:@[[MenuViewController new]]];
```

MainViewController creates a new navigation controller and in `viewDidLoad` the new navigation controller is added to the view with this:

```
[self.view addSubview:_navigationController.view];
```

Now I need to present another view controller. I have tried using this:

```
[_navigationController presentViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and this:

```
[[MainViewController navigationController] presentViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

+ (UINavigationController*)navigationController {
    return [[MainViewController sharedInstance]navigationController];
}
```

I get the same warning with both of them and the view controller loads, but I cannot navigate back. I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: What happen when you push it instead of modally present it?

Comment: you need not do this    [self.view addSubview:_navigationController.view];

Comment: [[MainViewController navigationController]setViewControllers:@[[MenuViewController new]]];[self.window setRootViewController:[MainViewController sharedInstance]];

Comment: @Thatguy - What happens is that it works perfectly and I bang my head on the desk for trying to write code at 4AM. ;) Please post this answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to **push it** instead of **modally present it** : [presentViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:) is a method from UIViewController to present modal VCs, whereas [pushViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController:animated:) pushes VCs in the navigation stack.

Try this instead :

```
[_navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
```